# Refund / devolución parcial del dinero con checkout básico

Tags: asp.net, .net, mercadopago

Alguien implementó una devolución parcial de un pago en algún lenguaje, con checkout básico?

En la página de MercadoPago (https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/basic-checkout/refund-cancel/) en mi caso con .NET, muestra que con MP.RefundPayment(:ID) y con MP.CancelPayment(:ID) podes devolver pagos totales, pero en la devolución parcial no informa ningún método para utilizar, sino un comando cURL:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
'https://api.mercadopago.com/collections/PAYMENT_ID/refunds?access_token=$AT' \
-d '{"amount":49.9, "metadata": {"reason":"some reason", "external_reference":"some_reference"}}'
```

Por lo tanto lo que hice fue lo siguiente:

```
Hashtable payment_approved = mp.post("/collections/" + order.PaymentID
+ "/refunds","{", 
     "\"amount\":" + "MONTO PARCIAL A DEVOLVER" + ", " +
     "\"metadata\": { " +
          "\"reason\":\"cancelled\"," +
          "\"external_reference\":\"" + order.OrderID + "\" +
       "}" + 
    "}");
```

Y el resultado fue un HTTP 201 (en vez de 200), y la devolución se hizo igual pero por el monto total, en vez de hacerse por el monto parcial que ingresé.

Comment: ¿En que pais estas implementando esta funcionalidad? por el dominio creo que argentina, pero me gustaría confirmarlo, esta funcionalidad no esta disponible en todos los paises.

Comment: Así es, en Argentina... por lo que había leído se implementó hace poco las devoluciones parciales.

Comment: Si, debería funcionar, revisaria un poco la formación del Body ya que una devolución se hace completa cuando no recibe parámetros, que al parecer es el caso, también es importante recordar que para Argentina las devoluciones parciales no son soportadas para pago recurrentes.